# Convert string to number groove in context.setProperty

Tags: string, groovy, int

I write mock service in SoapUI.

In groovy script next code:

```
context.setProperty("Number", '40817810123004000661');
```

When mock service is running in this field in the response from mock service I have text `Class java.lang.number` between value `40817810123004000661`.

I think that WSDL need specific type Number, not Integer.

And I try convert to int this way:

1. `context.setProperty("Number", ('40817810123004000661').toInteger);`
2. `context.setProperty("Number", params.toInt('40817810123004000661'));`
   this way not work.

Also, how I can convert a string to a number?

Comment: First, 40817810123004000661 is way too big to be stored in an integer.

Comment: It's even too big for a Long

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand your problem, but what if you simply do `context.setProperty("Number", 40817810123004000661);` without the single quotes around the number ?